# Angle of line at known point on known ellipse

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elliptic-equations

I have an oval/ellipse, $x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 = 1$. The ellipse is always centered at $(0,0)$.

I have a point on that ellipse, $(x, y)$.

I'm looking for the angle of the tangent at that point relative to the x axis (or y axis, I can work from that).

So I know I need to find $y=mx+b_1$.

I'm 95% certain that the $b$ from the ellipse is not the same as the $b_1$ from the line, the use of $b$ is just coincidental. I think $arctan(m)$ is the actual angle, but I haven't figured $m$ yet.

As far as I can figure,

$m = 0$ at $y = \pm b$ and $x = 0$ because it's a flat line, so then:

$m = \infty$ at $x = \pm a$ and $y = 0$ and I have no clue what to do with that.

Everything I'm finding seems really overcomplicated and a bit confusing, I vaguely recall this being a straightforward derivative.

This is being applied in a programming situation by someone who barely remembers algebra (me), so simple is best. Hold my hand like I haven't really done this stuff in decades.

Answer (score 3):

If you differentiate the equation
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$
with respect to $x$, using [implicit differentiation](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-ab/ab-differentiation-2-new/ab-3-2/a/implicit-differentiation-review), you get
$$\frac{2x}{a^2}+\frac{2y}{b^2}\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$
which simplifies to
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{b^2}{a^2}\frac{x}{y}$$
So the slope of the tangent is just
$$m=-\frac{b^2}{a^2}\frac{x}{y}$$
and the angle it makes with the $x$-axis is, as you say, $\arctan(m)$.

Comment: IMPLICIT DIFFERENTIATION thank you. Some lazy brain cell it getting lobotomized later...